LibreOffice Writer, strange window interactivity bug
I'm having a problem with LibreOffice:
If I open LibreOffice to write and then click anywhere, the interface of the window below appears!  If there is only the desktop below, then it interacts with the desktop instead.  It's as if I clicked on a hologram.
If I reduce or enlarge the LibreOffice window, sometimes it works again.  Perhaps someone can help me?
I made a short video to show what I mean: https://streamable.com/utz4fm

How did you install libreoffice? Or was it there from the beginning?

it was there from begining, i also uninstalled and reinstalled from flathub, but still the same

what version of Linux are you using? Flatpak's are not installed by default

I'm Using last version 24.04
I installed flatpak only afterwards because I also encountered these incompatibility problems with other apps like "krita" and downloading and installing the files directly from the official sites

I would like to try installing libreoffice writer again using the files downloaded from the official site, there are two types of download:
One (RPM) with an executable file but running it doesn't work
And another (DEB) with many many .deb packages that I don't know how to install
My hope is that if I can install it directly from the files provided by the official site, maybe this bug will no longer exist
https://it.libreoffice.org/download/download/

I use the flatpak on Ubuntu 24.04 and Kubuntu 24.04 and cannot reproduce the described problem (though the Video you provided is a dead link for me).
